# Reading data from the array with keys

Tags: php, arrays

This code:

```
$arr1 = array();

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
  $arr1[] = array('A'=>rand(0,5), 'B'=>rand(0,4));
}
```

generates array like this:

```
[0] array('A'=>0,[B]=>4)
[1] array('A'=>1,[B]=>3)
[2] array('A'=>3,[B]=>1)
//etc.
```

I need to get the different structure, i.e.:

```
$arr2 = array('A' => array(0,1,3),'B' => array(4,3,1));
```

so that later I can use `$arr2['A']`. If the array is created like it's shown in the first example, then `$arr1['A']` will not work.

How can I get `$arr2` using FOR loop like for `$arr1`. Hope I explained myself clear enough.

Comment: What have you tried.. Firstly you're only generating 1 random number.. so, what do you think the next step would be? Btw given you have basically answered yourself :)

Comment: @BugFinder: Sorry, I still don't understand how to get the $arr2 structure from FOR loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
$arr2 = array(
  'A' => array(),
  'B' => array()
);

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
  $arr2['A'][] = rand(0,5);
  $arr2['B'][] = rand(0,4);
}
```

If you want to convert existing `$arr1` into `$arr2`, try with:

```
$arr2 = array(
  'A' => array(),
  'B' => array()
);

foreach ( $arr1 as $value )
{
  $arr2['A'][] = $value['A'];
  $arr2['B'][] = $value['B'];
}
```